# Is there a "non-contrived" topological example where regular epics are not closed under composition?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Regular monics are not closed under composition, neither are regular epics. [Adámeck, Herrlich, and Strecker](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) provide examples of each. For regular monics, they use the category **FHaus** of functionally Hausdorff spaces (sec. 7J). For regular epics, their example lives in **Cat**.

It seems that regular epics are closed under composition in **FHaus**. (The proof that regular epics in **Top** coincide with quotient maps can be adapted to **FHaus**, and quotient maps are obviously closed under composition.) Is there a topological example of the failure of regular epics to be closed under composition?

Preferably I would like one in a full subcatgory of **Top**, and where the class of spaces has a "not too contrived" definition. **FHaus** is "not too contrived", by my lights.

Failing an example in a subcategory of **Top**, is there an example in **hTop** or a subcategory of it?